# how do I make the command running in a subprocess save to a file like object instead of a file?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this command that converts midi files to wav audio. So I run the command, the command writes the file to the disk and then I load the audio again from the disc. I know that the writing-reading routine is quite slow and in my use case efficiency is crucial. So I want to skip that part and just load the output to the python namespace as a file like object instead, doesn't even have to be that, just the audio data. how do I do that?

Comment: why not find some pythonic library instead?

Comment: I couldn't find any, the only thing I found is a wrapper around fluidsynth which does exactly the same as the CLI except less

Comment: what about https://pypi.org/project/midi2audio/

Comment: From project description:
"Easily synthesize MIDI to audio or just play it.

It provides a Python and command-line interface to the **FluidSynth** synthesizer to make it easy to use and suitable for scripting and batch processing. In contrast, most MIDI processing software is GUI-based."

Comment: there is [this package](https://pypi.org/project/pyFluidSynth/) though